# Append two hexadecimal long values in Java or C

Tags: java, c, hex, append

I am implementing the SHA-2 algorithm in Java. However, I have run into a problem. I need to append two hex values into one, but I am unable to do so. I tried appending the two as a string and using `Long.parseLong(appendedString)` but that causes a number format exception. Is there anyway I can do this in Java? If not is there anyway to do this in C and I'll just implement it in C? Thanks for reading.

Here is the code:

```
    String temp = h[0] + "" + h[1]; //Where h[0] and h[1] are two hex values stored as Long
    //I also tried String temp = String.valueOf(h[0]) + String.valueOf(h[1]); but no dice
    Long appended = Long.parseLong(temp); //Number format exception here
```

When I say append I mean something like: 0x6a09e667 + 0xbb67ae85 = 0x6a09e667bb67ae85

Comment: if your string is like `0xDEA0xDBEEF` this would explain the number format exception.

Comment: What do you mean by 'append'?

Comment: As in, 0x6a09e667 + 0xbb67ae85 = 0x6a09e667bb67ae85

Comment: Please write the string value of h[0] and h[1].

Comment: Well now that's interesting. The string result is 1779033703-1150833019 is Java not able to provide the literal representation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming your code looks something like this:

```
long hex1 = 0x6a09e667;
long hex2 = 0xbb67ae85;
```

and you want the output of `0x6a09e667bb67ae85`.

You can do this with some bit-shifting, such as the following:

```
long result = hex2 | (hex1 << 32);
```

Comment: I'm getting this when I use that: -4942790177982912921 Is this because of how System.out.println() works?

Comment: @D347th yes. You would need to get  println to print the hexadecimal value of result, which can probably be done via some google searching :)

Comment: @D347th not possible. Long values only store up to 64 bits, instead, you would need a `BigInt`, which IIRC, is available for java. So use that & it's supported bit shift functions instead. And yes, you would need to increase the shift.

Answer (score 1):

`0x6a09e667 + 0xbb67ae85` gives `0x6a09e6670xbb67ae85` which isn't valid. Try this code instead:

```
String temp = h[0] + h[1].substring( 2 ); // Strip "0x" from second string
```

Comment: I get the error substring(int) cannot be invoked on the primitive type long

Comment: My code only works when `h` is an array of Strings which contain hex values (as you wrote in your question). Please be more careful when you ask questions: Always use the values that the data types contain (and not the values which you imagine should be in the data types). That said, Richard's answer is correct.